# is there a better way to write this union query

Tags: sql-server

Hi I am trying to get the sum of wastage value from different table of the same date.I can achieve the desired output from the below query but it seems too big and repeted too.Is there any other way to shrink the query.Thanks in advance

```
select SUM(WasteValue) as WasteValue from(
select sum(im.Pur_Rate *wd.Item_Qty) as WasteValue  from [Item Master] im 
inner join [waste Details] wd on wd.Item_Code=im.Item_Code
inner join [waste Master] wm on wd.Waste_No=wm.Waste_No 
and CONVERT(date,wm.Waste_Date,120)BETWEEN '2016-06-30' 
and '2016-06-30' and im.Type_Code=1 and im.Branch_Code=0
union
select sum(im.Pur_Rate *wd.Item_Qty) as WasteValue  from [Item Master] im 
inner join [Counter Waste Details] wd on wd.Item_Code=im.Item_Code
inner join [Counter Waste Master] wm on wd.Waste_No=wm.Waste_No 
and CONVERT(date,wm.Waste_Date,120)BETWEEN '2016-06-30' 
and '2016-06-30' and im.Type_Code=1 and im.Branch_Code=0)Wastage
```

Comment: Union of two aggregated values?..

Comment: yep but from two independent tables.

Comment: You didn't get me: and what are you gonna do with it? No ids just two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect much with this data structure, but you can at least get the common parts out of the brackets like this:

```
select SUM(Pur_Rate * Item_Qty) as WasteValue from (
select im.Pur_Rate, wd.Item_Qty, wm.Waste_Date, im.Type_Code, im.Branch_Code
from [Item Master] im 
inner join [waste Details] wd on wd.Item_Code=im.Item_Code
inner join [waste Master] wm on wd.Waste_No=wm.Waste_No 
union
select im.Pur_Rate, wd.Item_Qty, wm.Waste_Date, im.Type_Code, im.Branch_Code
from [Item Master] im 
inner join [Counter Waste Details] wd on wd.Item_Code=im.Item_Code
inner join [Counter Waste Master] wm on wd.Waste_No=wm.Waste_No) Wastage
where CONVERT(date,Waste_Date,120) BETWEEN '2016-06-30' and '2016-06-30' 
and Type_Code=1 and Branch_Code=0
```

If I were you, I would look into combining tables with similar purposes (Waste Master and Counter Waste Master, for example) and having a flag to differentiate between the two.